# How to check whether a dynamically named checkbox is clicked?

Tags: jquery

```
   $("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append('<tr>'
                +   '<td><input type="checkbox" class="main" value="'+data.id+'" id=check'+data.id+'></td>'
                +   '<td>'+ data.brand +'</td>'
                +   '<td>'+ data.channel +'</td>'
                +   '<td>'+ data.content +'</td>'
                +   '<td>'+ data.destination_url +'</td>'
                +   '<td>'+ data.sentiment + '</td>'
                +   '<td>'+ data.post_date + '</td>'
                +   '<td><p class="click_star" ><i id='+data.id+' class="'+star_class_var+'"></i></p></td>'
                +   '<td><p class="click_flag" ><i  id='+data.id+' class="'+flag_class_var+'"></i></p></td>'
                +   '<td>'+ data.widget_flags +'</td>'


    + '</tr>'
        );
```

The above code segment is from my jquery and i need to check whether the checkbox in table is checked. its id and value is named dynamically. how to check whether that check box is clicked? i am a newbie in jquery. So please help

Comment: Use class selector like `$('.main:checkbox')`

Comment: Could you be more specific. I am new to this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('#tblEntAttributes tbody').on('click','input[type="checkbox"]',function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will delegate the on change event of checkboxes that are created dynamically

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).delegate("input[type='checkbox']","change",function(){
             alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function when it is checked then bind that function as soon as the checkbox is created (before data changes or is out of scope):

```
$("#tblEntAttributes tbody").append('<tr>'
            +   '<td><input type="checkbox" class="main" value="'+data.id+'" id="check'+data.id+'"></td>'
            +   '<td>'+ data.brand +'</td>'
            +   '<td>'+ data.channel +'</td>'
            +   '<td>'+ data.content +'</td>'
            +   '<td>'+ data.destination_url +'</td>'
            +   '<td>'+ data.sentiment + '</td>'
            +   '<td>'+ data.post_date + '</td>'
            +   '<td><p class="click_star" ><i id='+data.id+' class="'+star_class_var+'"></i></p></td>'
            +   '<td><p class="click_flag" ><i  id='+data.id+' class="'+flag_class_var+'"></i></p></td>'
            +   '<td>'+ data.widget_flags +'</td>'
            +   '</tr>');
$('#check'+data.id).change(function(){console.log($(this).attr('checked'))});
```